# Extensions of $C^k$ functions to the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Assume $\Omega \subset \mathbb R{^n} $ is an open connected smooth domain.  I have some propositions that I guess they are correct , but I want to be confident.

1. If $f\in C_0^k(\Omega) $ then $f\in C^k(\overline{\Omega})$; which measns $f$ has uniformly continuous derivatives k times.
2. If $ f \in C^k(\overline{\Omega})$ then we can extend $f$ to a function defined on a  closed set contain $\Omega $ (Or on the closure of  $\Omega$ ?) which this extention function is also $C^k $ (or continuous ?).
3. If $f\in C_0^k(\Omega) $ then there exists a $C^k $ (or continuous ?) function on $\overline{\Omega}$ that is zero on $\partial \Omega $ , agree with $f$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: "I have some proposition that I do not know that are they correct or not" could describe practically every question on this site.  I've edited the title into something more descriptive of the subject of your questions.  Feel free to improve it further.

Comment: What is the precise definition of the space $C^k_0(\Omega)$?  What does it mean for a function to be $C^k$ on a closed set like $\overline{\Omega}$?